# Error: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

**Error:** type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

how to solve this error. see my code, Anime Api calling with Getx.

Anime Api : https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime

`anime_api_server.dart`:

```
Future<List<Datum>> fetchAnimeData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List result = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      final List<Datum> respoList =
          result.map((json) => Datum.fromJson(json)).toList();
      return respoList;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load anime data');
    }
  }
```

`anime_controller.dart`:

```
AnimeServer apiService = AnimeServer();
  var isLoading = false.obs;
  var animedataList = <Datum>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchAnimeData();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchAnimeData() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);

      final List<Datum> animeList = await apiService.fetchAnimeData();

      animedataList.addAll(animeList);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: ${e.toString()}");
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

my debug console:

```
Restarted application in 5,852ms.
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created

[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized

[GETX] Instance "AnimeController" has been created

[GETX] Instance "AnimeController" has been initialized

I/flutter (10968): Error: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

please, guide this program issue fix on the comment.

Comment: Is `Datum` a custom class? If yes please share the code.

Comment: No, Datum Is api model.

Comment: check to second Answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Datum.fromJson` expect a string, but you've already decoded on `result`. Therefore use `.fromMap` where it will accept a map.

```dart
final List<Datum> respoList =
          result.map((e) => Datum.fromMap(e)).toList();
```

Comment: I implemented your answer in my program, then returned an error. 
The error: Null check operator uses on a null value.

Comment: you need to handle from your model class, you can use default value while reading the map in `fromMap`

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same issue i get response from API as _Map and its not subtype of Map<String, dynaimc>

if you want it as Map<K, V> you can try adding the `response.body`

like `Map<String, dynamic> myMap = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(response.body))`